# how to check if select option is selected from other page in new page in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

i have a `select` in my view, this `select` comes from previous page, i need to show `option` selected in previous page, how can i do it in laravel ?

this is view for previous page `select` :

```
<select class="col-12 pt-2 border" name="Mailroom">
        @foreach($indicators as $indicator)
                <option value="{{ $indicator->id }}">{{ $indicator->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```

this is view for current page `select` :

```
<select class="col-12 border mt-2 pt-2" name="indicator_id">
        @foreach($indicators as $indicator)
                <option value="{{ $indicator->id }}">{{ $indicator->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```

this is controller for previous page `select` :

```
Mailroom::create([
     'Mailroom' => $request['Mailroom'],
]);
```

this is controller for current page `select` :

```
Letter::create([
      'indicator_id' => $request['indicator_id'],
]);
```

and this is controller for show current page :

```
$mailroom = Mailroom::find($id);
$indicators = Indicator::all();
return view('Mailroom.complete', compact('indicators','mailroom'));
```

i don't know how to show selected option in previous page in current page.

Answer (score 0):

How about with session variable?

```
$_SESSION["selectedValue"]=$value;
```

and then on the other page:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["selectedValue"])){
    $value = $_SESSION["selectedValue"];
}
```

Comment: On the server side for each page.  The pages you have called "controllers".  On the client side (the pages your uses view), when the selection is made, you have to take the action of sending that value to the server.  The server then sets the session value, then it is available in all windows.